# Vertical exaggeration in 3D plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, aspect-ratio

I am plotting a cylinder in 3D space and would like to exaggerate the z axes to stretch the image.

Here is a simplified version of the code that I am using and corresponding image. I have changed the figure size to what I need, how do I stretch the actual plotted image so that the z axes is exaggerated?

```
def data_for_cylinder_along_z(center_x,center_y,radius,Dto,Dfrom):
    z = np.linspace(Dfrom, Dto, 50)
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)
    theta_grid, z_grid=np.meshgrid(theta, z)
    x_grid = radius*np.cos(theta_grid) + center_x
    y_grid = radius*np.sin(theta_grid) + center_y
    return x_grid,y_grid,z_grid

depth=7
depth_from=3

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
Xc,Yc,Zc = data_for_cylinder_along_z(0,0,0.02,depth,depth_from)
ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yc, Zc, alpha=0.5, color='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use  `set_box_aspect` . Here's the example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def data_for_cylinder_along_z(center_x,center_y,radius,Dto,Dfrom):
    z = np.linspace(Dfrom, Dto, 50)
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)
    theta_grid, z_grid=np.meshgrid(theta, z)
    x_grid = radius*np.cos(theta_grid) + center_x
    y_grid = radius*np.sin(theta_grid) + center_y
    return x_grid,y_grid,z_grid

depth=7
depth_from=3

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
Xc,Yc,Zc = data_for_cylinder_along_z(0,0,0.02,depth,depth_from)
ax.set_box_aspect([1,1,5])  # set aspect ratio
ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yc, Zc, alpha=0.5, color='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image: exapmle figure]